# Who hired Wade to scare Jeremy (the pizza guy)?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In *Deadpool*, Wade Wilson is hired to scare Jeremy the Pizza Guy from stalking Meghan Orlovsky.

But at around 2:20 in the below YouTube video, it seems as though this is the first time he has met Megan.

**So, who hired Wade to scare Jeremy?**

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was pretty solid, given the quote directly from the movie transcript and confirmation from the earlier version of the script. Is there anything else you'd want me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 31):

### Megan hired Wade.

> **WADE:** *Do you happen to know a Megan Orflosky? Get that right? Orflovsky?*
>
> [Jeremy nods].
>
> **WADE:** *Cause she knows you. Jeremy, I belong to a group of guys who take a dime to beat a fella down. And Megan, **she’s not made of
> money, but lucky for her, I got a soft spot.***

An [earlier version of the script](https://archive.org/stream/pdfy-1CeJQ_gog6XPXRwe/Deadpool%20Movie%20Leaked%20Script_djvu.txt) indicates that she managed to scrounge together about $600, most of which Wade ended up giving back to her, minus the cost of a beer.

---

It would appear that the hiring was done *indirectly* through the organisation that Wade works for. Offers are made for work and mercs can choose to accept or ignore contracts. Evidently Wade was willing to work below his *usual rate* because he felt for her.

> **Wade:** *Welcome to Sister Margaret's. **It's like a job fair for mercenaries.**
> Think of us as really f٭cked up tooth fairies except we knock out the
> teeth and take the cash. **You'd best hope we never see your name on a
> gold card.***

Comment: Yeah, but who hired Wade? B/c it seems it wasn't her?

Comment: @KyloRen - St Margarets seem to function as a clearing house for independent contracts. You make an offer, they stick it on a card. If a merc accepts it, they take the card and on completion they get the money that's held in escrow.

Comment: This directly follows the comics, where Wade picks up merc jobs from The Hellhouse (http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hellhouse).